# Match given strings stored in hash table with AVL trees in C

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable, avl-tree

Is there any way to ***match two data structures*** such as hash table and AVL trees? So for each string in hash table exists AVL tree? I would like to make it work in this way:

1. **find given string** in hash table
2. if such string doesn't exist -> add string to hash table and **create new AVL tree**
3. if the string has already been added in hash table -> **work with existing AVL tree**

So I can access to AVL tree paired with particular string and work (insert or delete nodes) with this tree. What do you suggest me to pair strings from hash table with AVL trees? Is it even possible to create more AVL trees and differentiate them?

[image: That's how it may look like]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Of course it is.  Whenever this is the answer, it is generally true that your question is way too broad.

Comment: It feels like there’s an XY Problem here.  Why do you need to storage structures for the same data? Choose the one that’s best for your work (probably the tree) and use just that. The tree can tell you whether it contains the word. If your worried about string comparison time, store a length and a hash in each mode of the tree.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm not sure he's trying to make an AVL tree match a hash table. Rather, I think he's asking if he can have a hash map where the key is a string and the value is an AVL tree. I'll admit, though, that reading the question in its current state does leave one wondering . . .

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, so imagine a function "void like (char *page, char *user)" which represents something like social network. Actually it inserts node with user name to AVL tree. But I must be able to insert this node to the correct tree (which refers to given page). If you have millions request per second, it should be pretty effective, so I thought the best way would be find the given string (page) in hash table and then pair it with the tree, so I can work with that tree. The question is if it is possible to pair string found in hash table with AVL tree? And how? :-)

Comment: @JimMischel I added a picture of how it may look like. In comment above I'm trying to describe my problem closer.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you storing the pointer to an AVL tree in the hash table structure.  So, yes, go for it.  Your hash table entry will have the hash, the string, and the pointer to the relevant AVL tree.  I'm not clear why AVL trees are beneficial, but that's a whole separate discussion, and not part of a "can I do it" discussion.  What you're trying isn't outrageous.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks a lot!